# Why do I receive a std::bad_alloc exception when running this code?

Tags: c++, bad-alloc

When I run the code below, I receive an error like this:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>   what():  std::bad_alloc
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information.

I think it may be caused by the "resize()" line, but I don't know how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long long n, l, r;
string x[3];

int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        x[i].resize(x[i].max_size());
    x[0] = '0';
    x[1] = '1';
    cin >> n >> l >> r;
    for (register long long i = 2; i <= n ; i++)
        x[i % 3] = x[(i - 2) % 3] + x[(i - 1) % 3];
    cout << x[n % 3].substr(l, r - l + 1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't resize your string to be so large. Did you try printing out the size you are attempting to resize to?

Comment: You don't actually need to resize them at all.  `c = a + b` will automatically allocate enough storage in `c`.

Comment: yes, it's 2147483647

Comment: Maybe look at the [documentation of `std::string::max_size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/max_size). The example provided (your implementation *may* be different) is pretty telling of just how much memory you may be needlessly trying to allocate. In your case, do you really need 6gB of space across three strings for whatever you're trying to do?

Comment: @godwing: If your program is windows 32 bit, you just used 200.001% of your computers memory for those two strings.

Comment: you tried to allocate 6gb of memory

Comment: @Paul Rooney @aschepler @WhozCraig @Mooing Duck @pm100 Thank you all, now I know the reason.I used `g++ .\cenbonacci.cpp -o -m32 .\cenbonacci.exe -g` while compiling, and I allocated too much memory. So I have to try another algorithm to solve the question.

Comment: Fun fact: compiling for 64-bit won't solve the problem either because most computers today don't have 9223372036854775807 bytes of memory.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding. You are trying to use 2 **billion** byte length strings. Three of them.

Comment: Adding to the code review - using `register` hasn't been useful since the 1980's. Somewhere around there compilers got smart enough to figure that out themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string::max_size()` is likely to be a large number such as `SIZE_MAX`, e.g. 4 GB on 32-bit system or the square of that on 64-bit systems. So your program runs out of memory.

Your program does not even need that allocation since you immediately overwrite the first 2 strings with a single-character string!  Maybe you were thinking of `reserve` instead of `resize`, but even then, you could reserve a much smaller amount than `max_size`.

NB. `register` is deprecated and will be removed in C++17.